# iPad safari don't show loaded images until slide the screen

Tags: javascript, ipad, dom, mobile-safari

i have a problem in iPad Safari. when i use Javascript to append image to div using elm.appendChild(img) the images don't appear until the screen is touched. the same code works perfect on IE,Firefox,Chrome,and android browsers.
i have uploaded video that shows the problem. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBN9fThDik8
is it related to the device ? or there some special code for loading images in iPad safari?
or any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

iPad (more so than iPhone as far as I've experienced, although that's just a gut feeling) is notorious for avoiding loading and rendering large resources unless it decides the user is going to see them.

How about faking the user input required to trigger the render, ie the scroll, after appending the image? Sample code here, may work:

```
function scroll(){
    var body = document.body;
    var xy   = [body.scrollLeft, body.scrollTop];
    window.scrollTo(xy[0],xy[1]+1);
    window.scrollTo(xy[0],xy[1]);
};
```

To be called immediately afterwards, eg:

```
appendImg();
scroll();
```